# Creating an Angular 5 component in execution time, after lazy-loading its dependencies

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to do something that may not be quite common. I'm trying to leverage Angular at its finest without needing many external dependencies, but for requirements reasons, I have to use one very specific library for date range picking ([this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-daterangepicker)), but it uses JQuery and Moment.js, aswell Bootstrap's CSS (but this one is already added).

In this case, I could simple load JQuery and Moment.js in the page, but that doesn't seem to be an intelligent approach: the bundle size would get bigger, and I have to optimize this app as much as I can.

Then, I came in to an idea: **why not lazy-load these dependencies, and then instantiate my component?** Seems like a good approach, right?

I'm using a provider that lets me include in the document scripts from a CDN, and it's working well. But now, I have to somehow *insert* this daterangepicker component, in execution time, when both libraries have loaded and resolved their promises.

**Current status:**

1 - I've got this parent class, which loads my dependencies (JQuery and Moment.js) on execution time:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LibraryLazyLoader } from '../../../providers/library_lazy_loader';
import { Ng4LoadingSpinnerService } from 'ng4-loading-spinner';

@Component({
  selector: 'date-selector',
  templateUrl: './date-selector.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./date-selector.component.css'],
  providers: [LibraryLazyLoader]
})
export class DateSelectorComponent implements OnInit {

  isLoaded = false;

  constructor(
    private libraryLoader:LibraryLazyLoader,
    private loadingSpinner:Ng4LoadingSpinnerService
  ){
    this.loadingSpinner.show();
    this.libraryLoader.loadJs('https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js')
        .subscribe(() => {
          console.log("JQuery included");
          this.libraryLoader.loadJs('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.3/moment.min.js')
            .subscribe(() => {
              console.log("Moment.js included");
              this.loadingSpinner.hide();
              this.isLoaded = true;
            })
         })
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

}
```

2 - It's template is just like this:

```
<button>Load js</button>
<div *ngIf="isLoaded">
  <input daterangepicker>
</div>
```

The idea is, when both libraries are loaded, the isLoaded boolean should provoke the view to update with the daterangepicker directive correctly loading, and permitting me using the component.

Thing is, this doesn't work. And though I'm not going to use this in the project, I'm very curious about how it could work, since it could permit us build much more optimized pages! Lazy loading modules are nice, but the next step is to lazy load components, I think. Someone correct me if this approach is not good, but I think it can be a really good improvement to Angular.

So, any ideas?

Comment: Hi @Zerok, why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as an idea, you could add a guard to the route which loads the scripts and once the scripts are loaded the component can be loaded.

e.g. extending the Angular documentation example. You could just add a guard to resolve the dependencies before navigating to the view which needs them

```
@Injectable()
class TeamResolver implements Resolve<any> {

  resolve(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<any>|Promise<any>|any {
    return Promise.all([
import("https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"), 
import("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.3/moment.min.js")
])
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: 'team/:id',
        component: TeamCmp,
        resolve: {
          team: TeamResolver
        }
      }
    ])
  ],
  providers: [TeamResolver]
})
class AppModule {}
```

Also, I am not sure what the issue is with your example above?  As a guess, I would say that you are seeing nothing happen and I would say that is down to needing to let Angular know to run the cycle again. Maybe try

```
setTimeout(() => {
   this.loadingSpinner.hide();
   this.isLoaded = true;
})
```

Comment: Could you add an example?